# Is it correct and natural to say "arrive to my phone number"?

Tags: word-usage

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say arrive to my phone number? For example:

> I topped up my phone an hour ago, but the payment hasn't **arrived to my phone number** yet.

Does the sentence sound natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't sound natural to me.

You are using "phone number" as a metonym for "telephone company account" and that isn't common usage in my experience. Furthermore "arrive to" is not proper grammar here regardless of the object.

I would instead use:

> I topped up my phone an hour ago, but the payment hasn't **hit**<sup>1</sup> **my account** yet.

or

> I topped up my phone an hour ago, but the payment hasn't **gone through** yet.

---

<sup>1</sup> [**hit**, verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit#Etymology_1):

> 6. (*heading*) *To attain, to achieve.*
>    6.1 (*transitive, informal*) To reach or achieve. *The movie **hits** theaters in December.*

Comment: If you are being formal or pedantic you would say "The top up amount has not been credited to my account yet". You could also say "The top up money has not been credited to my _phone_ yet.