# What is the correct preposition in "return the call TO this number"?

Tags: prepositions

I got the following phrase from an answering machine:

> We can return your call at this number.

Is the preposition "at" correct here? Shouldn't it be "to" or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct and natural to say "arrive to my phone number"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294515/is-it-correct-and-natural-to-say-arrive-to-my-phone-number)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it seems another issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"At", "to", and "on" are all used in connection with telephone numbers, but in different ways.

The first two are easy to explain. Speaking about your *physical* location, you would say "I'm *at* [location]", but "I'm going *to* [destination]". Likewise, some English speakers (predominantly US English speakers) use 'at' in connection with their own telephone number (eg "you can reach me *at* this number") and 'to' in connection with a number they are trying to reach (eg "I'm trying to make a call *to* [number]".

"On" is more universal, and I believe we say this more in British English. You can say "I'm *on* this number" as well as "I was trying to call you *on* this number".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So, in this case, "to" or "on" would be more appropriate, as they are talking about calling to a number rather than being reachable themselves at the number, right?

Comment: @JānisElmeris "On" seems most natural to me in your example.

Answer (score 0):

> We can return your call at this number.

is, at least in US English, confusing to the point of incomprehensibility. The word "to" would normally be used to refer to the destination number. But "return your call" would normally involve the source number. Moreover  such a message would not usually refer to any number, as the listener would understand that the return call would come **from** the number that s/he called, and probably does not much care what number the call will be returned from.

> I'm on 555-1234 would be very unusual in US usage. "on" is not frequently used to indicate  the number from which a person has called, and it is somewhat uncommon to mention that number at all. But if it is to be mentioned, the usual way would be something like:

> I am calling from 555-1234.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The "number" here is not meant the number the call is going to be made from, but the number that will be called to. With the phrase, the company is informing the client (the caller) that they have automatically logged the number the client is currently calling from, and will call back to that number. Probably to reassure that no further action from the caller is necessary (or supported), like providing a number they can be reached at, as the company already has the number and will use it when returning the call.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could use "at" or "on".

"At" is commonly used in American English while "on" is usually used in British English.

Sometimes, you could use "from" instead. e.g. "I am returning the missed call from [phone number]."